# Gather Stats Required After Truncate and Insert?

Tags: oracle, database-performance

I needed to truncate and reload a table.

I learned that truncate needs stats gathering on the table as its successor process so the database gets the actual statistics, otherwise previous stats are not cleared by the truncate statement.

After doing these two operations (truncate and stats gathering on the empty table), ran the insert... but don't see new statistics in all_tab_statistics table for my table. Sample_size is still 0.

Why is that? Shouldn't have Oracle done the automatic stats gathering after the insert?

Do I need to rerun the stats or is it just fine considering the performance around this table (please note it's going to truncate and reload each time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a long time since I posted my question above. But recently, we again faced the similar situation and this time below steps worked towards a much better performance on a table with 800 million rows.

1. Take a backup of the original table.
2. Truncate the original table.
3. Gather stats on the truncated table, so that statistics show 0 in the DB. Us CASCADE=>TRUE in the command to also include indexes in the process.
4. Drop the indexes on the truncated table and Insert the required data from the backup table.
5. Recreate the indexes and gather stats again (ofcourse, with CASCADE=>TRUE; however recreation of the indexes should ideally have calculated the appropriate stats).
6. Drop the backup table if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach.  It has the advantage of the table always being present.

1. Create an empty new table like the old one.
2. Load the data into the new table.  This is the slowest step.
3. Do whatever cleanup you might need, such as refreshing the statistics.
4. `RENAME` tables to swap the new table in place.  This step is fast enough so you won't notice.